# 'loss of life" VS "loss of lives"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. This year’s target is reducing loss of **life**.

In the context, it means to reduce fatalities. In my opinion, since there are many lives invovled, the above sentence should be worded like this:

> 2. This year’s target is reducing loss of **lives**.

Am I right, or more possibly wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Life is used as a mass (non-count) noun in "loss of life". It means "one death or more". The death of one person is a loss of life. "Lives" is a plural noun. "Loss of lives" means "more than one death". In the context of reducing an expected large future fatality figure, either would be understood, but a native speaker might hear "loss of lives" and assume you don't care much if one person dies.